# Auto-generate transliterated cyrillic slugs with friendly_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, friendly-id, transliteration

I want to implement `friendly_id` into existing model. Application uses `russian` gem, which handles new or hand-saved records well, but it doesn't seem to work when I update records from the command line.

`User.find_each(&:save)` (as friendly_id docs syggested) generate slugs like `--<id>`.

I used custom normalize method to provide transliterated slug:

```
def normalize_friendly_id(input)
  Russian.transliterate input.to_s.mb_chars.downcase
end
```

but it definitely may miss some edge cases, and handles string differently from "normal" workflow. What I'm looking for is the way to reuse regular create/update flow and native behavior.

Answer (score 10):

The best way to resolve this problem:

**1) Add [gem 'babosa'](https://github.com/norman/babosa) n your Gemfile**

```
gem 'friendly_id'
gem 'babosa'
```

**2) Owerride friendly_id's method in your model**

```
def normalize_friendly_id(text)
  text.to_slug.transliterate(:russian).normalize.to_s
end
```

Comment: now it's `text.to_slug.transliterate(:russian).normalize.to_s`